# Import Node into new Document

Tags: java, domdocument

I'm trying to import a node from a base-document into a new document but when I use the Document.importNode() method, it generates an exception. The funny part is that this exception does not contain a message so I'm pretty much blind except for the stack-trace. (I'm new to java)

Here is my method that will create a new document and import the node:

- this.Builder = DocumentBuilder
- this.Element = Node

Code:

```
public XMLSelection extract ()
{
    if (this.Element != null)
    {
        try
        {
            Document newDoc = this.Builder.newDocument();
            Node node = newDoc.importNode(this.Element, true);

            newDoc.appendChild(node);
            return new XMLSelection(newDoc);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Debug.error("XMLSelection::extract", e);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And the stack-trace:

```
02-06 14:27:53.328: W/System.err(9082): org.w3c.dom.DOMException
02-06 14:27:53.328: W/System.err(9082):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.NodeImpl.setNameNS(NodeImpl.java:227)
02-06 14:27:53.328: W/System.err(9082):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.ElementImpl.(ElementImpl.java:50)
02-06 14:27:53.328: W/System.err(9082):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.DocumentImpl.createElementNS(DocumentImpl.java:336)
02-06 14:27:53.328: W/System.err(9082):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.DocumentImpl.shallowCopy(DocumentImpl.java:156)
02-06 14:27:53.328: W/System.err(9082):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.DocumentImpl.cloneOrImportNode(DocumentImpl.java:208)
02-06 14:27:53.328: W/System.err(9082):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.DocumentImpl.importNode(DocumentImpl.java:222)
02-06 14:27:53.328: W/System.err(9082):     at com.xxxx.xxxx.XMLSelection.extract(XMLSelection.java:57)
```

Comment: Well, the DOMException is thrown because of the element (or a child element) missing a qualified name. Can you dump the XML that causes this error?

Comment: I'm trying to create a new document based on the <body> tag. Here is the xml: [link](http://pastebin.com/V6eGCYD0)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try a `cloneNode` followed by an `adoptNode` to use a child element as the root element of a new `Document`.

```
    String xml = "<hello><world /></hello>";
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document document0 = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
        Document document1 = db.newDocument();


        NodeList nodeList = document0.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();
        document1.appendChild(document1.adoptNode(nodeList.item(0).cloneNode(true)));

        // Serialize the two documents to check that the copy was correct.
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document0), new StreamResult(output));
        System.out.println(output.toString("UTF-8"));

        output.reset();
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document1), new StreamResult(output));
        System.out.println(output.toString("UTF-8"));
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    } catch (SAXException e) {
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
    }
```

Comment: When using eclipse the Document.adoptNode() is undefined. (import org.w3c.dom.Document;). Is there another package I should use?

Comment: Hm, what version of Android are you targeting? adoptNode is API level 8 if i dont remember totally wrong.

Comment: SDK 7 (Android 2.1). Should I up the SDK or is there a workaround?

Comment: XML in API level before 8 is pretty crummy, and 2.1 has *rather* small [market share](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html) - I'd up it - but that depends on your requirements.

Comment: Quick question, is the new document not a "real" document from the factory? I've set the API to 8 and the adoptNode method is now defined, but still the same error occur. My best guess is that the "document01" in your example is not valid, nor my approach? My intention is not to output this document but to create a new object (XMLSelection) based on the NodeList. Maybe my approach to create a new Document is not optimized. I still want to access the getElementsByTagName method using the selection (Node).

Comment: It still crashes on your device even with appendChild(adoptNode(cloneNode)))? I tested with the XML you uploaded in pastebin and `document1` in the example would act as a "completely normal" `Document`. Can you attach the stack trace to your question with the modified approach?

Comment: Ok, in both of my tries I used the cloneNode method but after a couple of tests it seems that this breaks something. Removing the cloneNode solved it. Thank you so much for all the help!

Comment: btw: If you don't rely on the "original" `Document` to stay the same there's no need to clone the node - so no worries in that case.